# Excel code to return specific values from another worksheet

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have an excel file that lists multiple students and courses they've taken and when they were taken. The worksheet is set up so that the students are listed in rows and the courses are in columns along with the dates. I created a calendar on a separate worksheet to show a snapshot view of the students and their courses taken. I am struggling with how to feed the data into the Calendar. Basically, the logic is that I need to search through (or loop through) an array of non-adjacent cells named StatusArray and if there is a value present then I need it to return the student ID and the associated Course name. The kicker is that there are sometimes multiple courses per student so I need to make sure it returns all of them, each on a new line. And the status columns all have formulas in them because they are generated based on the dates entered.

Example:
Worksheet 1 columns - Student ID, name, address, course status, start date, end date, grade, course status, start date, end date, grade, ......

I need it to read through the course status columns and (when not blank) return the status header for the status column in J and the student ID in column C of the Calendar worksheet. Bonus if it returns Name, Address, Phone, and comments as well!

I am completely stuck as to how to do this!

Comment: Can you provide some sample data (either in a table or with an image) and expected results? Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I believe new user restrictions (<10 rep) don't allow images.  I also don't really follow the layout.

Comment: So many problems seem to center around working with denormalized data.

Comment: I didn't see anywhere I could add a sample sheet to show an example

Comment: originally I listed each student 15 times (the number of courses there are) and used VLOOKUP and MATCH to denote which courses were taken and then filtered by that column to show all courses taken. unfortunately there are around 2500 students so my file size is now way out of control.

Comment: is there a way I can upload the file?

Answer (score 0):

A brute-force approach: Let's assume you have 4 repeating blocks of "status/start/end/grade" information. I understand 4 course blocks is the most any student has, but some students have data populated in three or fewer blocks.

First, copy only the region of data that has student ID, name & address. Paste it immediately below the existing list of students. Repeat until you have a total of 4 sets of student information. The first set is your original, then 3 redundant copies below.

Next, cut the right-most (4th) block of status/etc. information, and paste it next to the 1st repeated section of students. Make sure you align the pasted status column with the first block's status column. Repeat this exercise two more times, cutting out the rightmost block of status etc. and pasting next to the next section of redundant student information.

You should now have a table with only 7 columns of data: the first three are student ID, name & address, same as before. The next four columns are course status, start, end & grade. Now, you should be able to simply filter the "status" column for what you're looking for.

P.s. I don't usually recommend brute-force, but in this case it's impossible to code something more elegant without a lot more specifics about your layout. This solution should be quick and easy assuming you don't have a ton of data to manipulate and assuming you don't need to do this very often.